# remap ':' to maintain last command, and erase all char if any key other than <CR> was pressed

Tags: command-line, functions, repeated-commands

As the title stated, **remap ':' to maintain last command, and erase all char if any key other than `<CR>` was pressed.**

**possible use cases:**

- I have typed a long command, and I may or may not modified it, then re-run it.
- I save a lot, so I want type `:`, then visually verify `:w` is there, then type `<CR>` to proceed. -- I have remapped `:saveas<CR>` to `<Leader>s`.

**things that are not what I pursue:**

- I know about `q:` or `<C-f>` in cmdline mode to open the mini buffer to edit command.
- I know type `@:` then `@@` to repeat command.
- I know type `<C-p>` or `<Up>` in cmdline mode.

**a little more on motivation:**

Repeat with `register/macro` is great and is really handy for some task.

But here I want a more consistent and safer (visually verification/feedback) way to re-run last command, with fewer key stroke.

**Is that possible? or not trivially implementable at all??**

**======== EDIT ========**

Based on @Karl's comment, I think the problem could be implemented via a function definition and a `nnoremap`. The function consist three parts:

1. echo last command `getreg(':')`, then get `char` with `getchar`
2. if `char == '^M'`, re-execute last command.
3. otherwise, open command line and act accordingly.

My first attempt is as below: -- (based on @grodzik's  answer and @Karl's idea in the comment)

```
func! Show_last_command_and_exec()
    echo ':'.getreg(':')
    try
        let char = getchar()
    catch /^Vim:Interrupt$/
        let char = "\<Esc>"
    endtry
    if char == "^M"
        exec getreg(':')
        " not work, don't know why, tried with previous comand be `:pwd`
    else
        " not work, don't know which function or command should be used.
        " below are failed attempt.
        " normal! :
        " call feedkeys(char)
        " exec ':'.char
    endif
endfunc

nnore : :call Show_last_command_and_exec()<CR>
```

But unfortunately, except the trivial first echo part, neither work yet.
I post my attempt (though failed currently) here, hope someone interested may implement a better one that work nicely.

P.S. as @grodzik said in his answer, the "^M" should be replaced with real `<CR>` sign.

Comment: P.P.S. I observed the stated behavior in `evil-mode` of `emacs`, and thought, cool, how can I re-implement it with `vimscript` so I can use it in `vim`.

Comment: First part is quite easy: `nnoremap : :<C-p>`. Not sure about erasing it when pressing something else than `<CR>`

Comment: Your are right, the first part is quite easy. For erase part, I have no clue yet.

Comment: How about using `<C-u>` to erase whole line in Ex-mode? I know it's extra key press, but auto erasing seems impossible.

Comment: yeah, I also doubt I was over-engineer here. Or I should just be happy with `<C-p>`, `<C-u>` and `<C-f>` in cmdline mode.

Comment: I don't have time to implement, but I think this could work: Map `:` to a function that first displays the last executed command with an `echo`. Then it get's the next char with `getchar()` and similar to @grodzik's function it either starts a new command line with the character entered, or if you press `<cr>` it executes the last command.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg thx for your reply, really helpful. Yes, we could just `echo` last command, then base on contents of `getchar()` act accordingly. But, as a vimscript newbie, I don't know which functions should be used. Though I do post my current version in the edit of problem, sadly which not work yet.

Comment: See my answer, I think my version should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should solve your issue:

```
nnoremap <expr> : ShowLastCmd()

function! ShowLastCmd()
  echohl ModeMsg
  echo ':' . getreg(':')
  echohl None

  while 1
    try
      let char = getchar()
      if char == '^\d\+$' || type(char) == 0
        let char = nr2char(char)
      endif
    catch /^Vim:Interrupt$/
      return ''
    endtry

    if char == "\<cursorhold>"
      continue
    elseif char == "\<cr>"
      return ':' . getreg(':') . "\<cr>"
    else
      return ':' . char
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction
```

The `while` loops is there to catch the `<cursorhold>` key event.

Comment: thx Karl, It works like a charm, really nice!! A minor note, when last command's echo contents exceed one page, eg `reg`, then press `:` do not show last command. -- is that a case of `<cursorhold>` or vim in a different mode other than normal mode?  P.S. I do read `:h <cursorhold>` and `CursorHold-example`, and find it not very helpful here for me.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If I do `:reg`, enter, then do `:`, there is not problem. I've updated the code to fix the problem with `<cursorhold>` (i.e., if you did `:` and waited with the old version it would not do what you wanted).

Comment: sorry for the unclearness, the problem has nothing to do with `:reg`, the problem is when last command echo many contents -- there is **--More--** at the bottom of echo erea -- eg, open 100+ file then type `:ls`. then it fails.  P.S. or some option matters here?

Comment: besides that, it works fine. -- though, it has basically no practical problem for me. thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I've fixed that minor issue now. :)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of hacking, I actually found a way to achive that:

```
function! AutoErase()
  setlocal cursorline
  normal Gk
  redraw!
  try
    let char = getchar()
  catch /^Vim:Interrupt$/
    let char = "\<Esc>"
  endtry
  if char == '^\d\+$' || type(char) == 0
    let char = nr2char(char)
  endif " It is the ascii code.
  if char == "^M"
    call feedkeys('^M')
  else
    execute "normal Gi" . char
    startinsert!
  endif
endfunction

autocmd CmdwinEnter * call AutoErase()
nnoremap : q:
```

This will show Command Window though and command to be executed when pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the one highlited. Also, it may be required to change in `.vimrc` signs with `^M` into real `<CR>` signs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I copy the code into `.vimrc` and start vim with `vim -u .vimrc`, also I do change `^M` to true ascii `<CR>`, and it not work correctly. type `:` open Command Window immediately.

Comment: then I type `:pwd` and excute. after that, when I type `:` again, last command was not show, just the Command Window open.

Comment: thanks for your help, really helpful and eye-opening, but for this specific problem, I think I should keep it simple, and do with builtin key, since vim is already efficient enough, at least for my own need.

Comment: Try adding ` -N` to the command, which will activate `nocompatible` mode

Comment: my bad, the `compatible` mode!! thanks, works as stated, nice job!  P.S,, for the use case, I might still stay away from that, since IMO open Command Window as the default is too intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very short mapping that will achieve roughly what you're asking, by using the command-line window and select mode:

```
nnoremap : :<Up><C-F>gH
```

It recalls the previous command with `<Up>`, opens the command-line window with `<C-F>` and then enters linewise select mode with `gH`.

If you then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the command is run, but if you type anything else, the current selection will be replaced.